# Remove selected item from the list

Tags: jquery

When I select option, jQuery adds that option text on list. Now I want when I click on link to remove selected text from that list. I have something like this:

```
function getText(){
    $('#change').on('change',function(){
        conceptName ='<li>' + $('#change').find(":selected").text() + ' ( ' + $('#select').find(":selected").text() + ' ) <a  class="speclist-remove"></a></li>';
        $('ol').append(conceptName);    
        $('a ').remove(conceptName);
    });     
}
```

jquery ads this html dinamically:

```
var content_next='<div id="popUpDiv"  class="popup-box header-popup-wrapper">'+
    '<h5>Saznajte prvi</h5>'+
    '<section class="login">'+
    '<p>Izaberite destinacije za koje želite da primate obaveštenja:</p><form >'+
    '<label>Država:</label>'+
    '<div class="styleSelect"><select class="units" id="select"><option value="1">Sve ponude</option><option value="2">Srbija</option><option value="3">Grcka</option></select></div>'+
    '<label class="margin-top7px">Destinacija:</label>'+
    '<div class="styleSelect"><select class="units" id="change"><option value="1">Sve ponude</option><option value="2">Novi Sad</option><option value="3">Beograd</option></select></div>'+
    '<input  type="submit" value="Potvrdi" class="margin-top7px"><input  type="submit" value="Odjava" class="margin-top7px" id="close"></form><div><p>Trenutno pratite ponude za:</p><ol></ol></div></section></div>';
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: from which list you want to remove? can you add html ?

Comment: Jquery dynamically ads html.

Comment: conceptName value is of selected value from #change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get closest parent li and use remove function on anchor click event

```
$(".speclist-remove").on("click", function(){
$(this).closest("li").remove();
$('#change').prop("disabled", flase);
});
```

To disable

```
$('#change').on('change',function(){
if($(this).val()){
$(this).prop("disabled",true);
}
```

});

Comment: How can i disable/enable select option? When i select option it should be disabled and when i remove it from list enabled.

Comment: but when you disable select on value select then you can not drop down select, if updated solution is not what you are looking for then please comment

Comment: I want to disable options,not select. when i click on option it ads that options text in <ul><li>,and that option should be disabled. But when i click on link with class speclist-remove i want that option to be enabled again,so that i can click again on it.

Comment: give me your demo html I will update code accordingly. just select html

Comment: <select class="units" id="change"><option value="1">Sve ponude</option><option value="2">Novi Sad</option><option value="3">Beograd</option></select>